How to generate folder hierarchy report of a document library in SharePoint Online?
We have a large library containing a significant number of folders and files and we would like to view the folder hierarchy (tree view) of each folder.

One option is "Generate file plan report". You'll get an excel file where your folders structure will be listed:

for this, you'd go to Library settings -> More library Settings -> Generate file plan report
a site collection feature called "Reporting" must be activated
Another option is to "Enable Tree View" under site settings -> Navigation Elements. Your folder structure will be displayed on the left:

Since first option might be very slow on big libraries and the second option might be inconvenient, you might choose a custom PowerShell script...

If you need the data in CSV format or just see the folder structure in the browser use the earlier suggested methods.
If you need to generate a tree structure with folders+documents in the browser (similar to windows explorer) you need to use apps. See list.

Here are two methods.
1.Use the "Export to Excel" feature.

2.Run the following PowerShell commands to get the structure of folders, subfolders and files.
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://YourSiteURL"
$ListName= "YourListName"
$ReportOutput = "C:\YourPath\ListInventory.csv"
  
#Connect to SharePoint Online site
Connect-PnPOnline $SiteURL -Interactive
  
#Array to store results
$Results = @()
  
#Get all Items from the document library
$List  = Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 5000
Write-host "Total Number of Items in the List:"$List.ItemCount
 
$ItemCounter = 0
#Iterate through each item
Foreach ($Item in $ListItems)
{
        #If you don't need to display certain information, you can delete it.
        $Results += New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
            Name              = $Item["FileLeafRef"]
            Type              = $Item.FileSystemObjectType
            FileType          = $Item["File_x0020_Type"]
            RelativeURL       = $Item["FileRef"]
            CreatedBy         = $Item["Author"].Email
            CreatedOn         = $Item["Created"]
        })
    $ItemCounter++
    Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($ItemCounter / ($List.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity "Processing Items $ItemCounter of $($List.ItemCount)" -Status "Getting Metadata from Item '$($Item['FileLeafRef'])"         
}
 
#Export the results to CSV
$Results | Export-Csv -Path $ReportOutput -NoTypeInformation
Write-host "Document Library Inventory Exported to CSV Successfully!"

